# Option to configure TLS version in rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog

Is it possible to configure the minimum TLS version supported by rsyslog?

For eg., we would like an option to choose one of the following

TLS 1.0 ( this should allow TLS connection over version 1.0, 1.1,1.2 and future version)
TLS 1.1 ( this should allow TLS connection over version 1.1,1.2 and future version)
TLS 1.2 ( this should allow TLS connection over version 1.2 and future version)

I think by default it is supporting TLS1.0 as the minimum TLS version.   Would like to know if this is configurable.

Answer (score 1):

As of [rsyslog 8.29, yes](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imtcp.html#gnutlsprioritystring) a [gnutls priority string](https://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Priority-Strings.html) is configurable.  An [example config loading the module](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/master/tests/sndrcv_tls_priorityString.sh) is in the test suite.

No built-in single keyword exists that restrict both the ciphers and the protocol to say TLS 1.2+. You might take a keyword you like and remove the broken things, such as by appending  `:-VERS-SSL3.0:-VERS-DTLS1.0:-VERS-TLS1.0:-VERS-TLS1.1`.

This is just for rsyslog. Repeat for other applications using gnutls.